# Python's requests library doesn't get the full html file

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm learning web scraping and trying to get the links from the top results of Google when searching for a specific term.
This is my code so far:

```
import requests

search_term = str(input('Search for: '))
search_results = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}')
```

When I print *search_results* like so:

```
print(search_results.text())
```

Then I only get a fraction of the HTML file I should get. When I save the HTML code in *search_results* and run it in chrome it makes it clear that the *request.get* function only gets the top part of the google search results page.

As an example, if I input "cats" as the *search_term*, save the HTML I get and run it in chrome, I only get the top part, as shown in the picture: [image]

Help much appreciated.

Comment: try: 'https://www.google.com/search?%20start=0%20&num=10%20&q=cats'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

for an example

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("cats")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
time.sleep(5) 
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into selenium. I've seen requests be used like I do and it gets the whole HTML file, so do you know why it didn't work for me?

Comment: Because the Google search API is commercial: [Custom Search JSON](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#pricing)
Unless you search through the browser

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `search_results.text` instead of `search_results.text()` since there's no `text()` method in `requests` library. It has [`.text` method which will automatically decode content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

There's no need for `selenium`. It's probably because you haven't sent a `user-agent` request headers.

The most often problem why you don't see the same results as in your browser is because there's no `user-agent` being passed into request `headers` thus when no `user-agent` is specified while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot/script, then it blocks a request (or whatever it does) and you receive a different HTML with different CSS selectors and some sort of an error. Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Google and figuring out why certain things don't work as they should, and you don't have to maintain the parser over time. Instead, you need to grab the data you want from the structured JSON. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to create minecraft server",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result["link"], sep="\n")

----------
'''
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
# other results
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.